# How exactly to make consensus when Chaincode has coding block of authority or event?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I read protocol specification https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#5-byzantine-consensus-1

I am wondering:

1. What exactly happened when chaincode has an coding block of authority?
2. What exactly happened when chaincode has an coding block of event?

For example, there are A,B,C,D are four parties, they are runing on four Validating Peers. 
The There is a coding block of authority in chaincode A , only party A has the authority to run the coding block. 
And there is a coding block of event in chaincode A, only party A can get the result of event.

So only party A can run into the coding block. Party B, C, D can not run into the coding block.

How PBFT make consensus of A,B,C,D in such situation?

Comment: So how we can get the final consensus of the whole chaincode? I image that coding block of event and authority can broadcasting its only result to other VPs. could you please kindly check and reivew?

Or

Let me change my question, what kind of code or API code needs consensus? Is it all of the chaincode? setEvent()? PutState()?

Comment: "coding block of authority" - are we speaking about private smart contracts where source code is encrypted by party A certificate ?

Comment: "coding block of authority" - like the "isCaller" func in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management.go
 --- only caller can run into the "transfer" and "assign"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the comments above,  this question can be changed to something like this:

“An example [asset_management.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management.go) has “isCaller” method which can be executed only by “caller”. How PBFT consensus can be reached in this case? ”

but this definition would be incorrect because all A, B, C and D Validation Peers can execute code in  “transfer”, “assign” and “isCaller” if transaction is signed with original “admin” certificate.

Let’s go through this example and study it step by step.

1. “asset_management.go” chaincode can be deployed to the ledger by any user with role “client”
2. During deployment, in `Init` method, this user’s certificate will be saved in the ledger as “admin”:

   ```
   adminCert, err := stub.GetCallerMetadata()
   ...
   stub.PutState("admin", adminCert)
   ```
3. When somebody would like to submit `assign` or `transfer` transaction into the ledger he has to sign this request with his own certificate
4. This request will be propagated to all VP in the network.
5. Each of VP will load “admin” certificate from the ledger and compare it to the certificate which was used to sign this particular request:

   ```
   adminCertificate, err := stub.GetState("admin")
   ...
   ok, err := t.isCaller(stub, adminCertificate)
   ```

If certificates **are not the same** - this request will not be accepted by VPs during PBFT consensus phase.

If certificates **are the same** - all VPs will know that this request is signed by original “caller” and will proceed with chaincode execution because they have all necessary information to do so.

Comment: Thank you. **1.** `This request will be propagated to all VP in the network.` does it means a broadcasting method? if it is an kindly of broadcasting, what contents were broadcasted? **2.**`If certificates are not the same and are the same` Can I think the PBFT consensus happens in each line of chaincode program coding? Otherwise, how PBFT can know `the same` or `not the same` in the middle of chaincode program?

Comment: 1. Each validation peer keeps open connection with all other VPs in the network. As a first step in consensus - the leader (one of VP who was selected as a leader) will prepare ordered list of transactions and broadcast it to other validation peers. The content is Chaincode id, function name, parameters etc.

Comment: 2. No, consensus in not a “each line” level event. Each validation peer will execute all transaction in a list, then VP will calculate hash for new “state of the world”, then VP will calculate final hash for entire block. Then VP will check if other VPs have the same final hash. PBFT don’t care about intermediate results, in consensus phase PBFT verify that HASH for block is the same for all VPs and it means that all transactions were executed with the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your continues help. Let's come back the question. `PBFT don’t care about intermediate results, in consensus phase PBFT verify that HASH for block is the same for all VPs` How can PBFT know the “admin” certificate in the middle of consensus? If PBFT do not keep to compare in the middle of consensus, How does PBFT make `Each of VP will load “admin” certificate from the ledger and compare it to the certificate which was used to sign this particular request`

Comment: PBFT is not involved in transaction execution. VP has it’s own copy of entire ledger and chaincode can get an access to admin certificate at any time “adminCertificate, err := stub.GetState(“admin")". And, as a result, chaincode can verify if user, who submitted transaction is admin. Result of this transaction execution (both “rejected” or “executed successfully”) will be included in ledger and state of the world will be updated correspondingly. On a next step VP will check if they do have the same state of the world and decide if consensus is reached.

Comment: Let me try to Summary, the answer is that all VPs can get an access to admin certificate at any time “adminCertificate, err := stub.GetState(“admin")". It is not correct that only the VP of admin can run the “adminCertificate, err := stub.GetState(“admin")".

Comment: Yes, your summary is right. The User with “client” rights can deploy chaincode (and become admin) but it doesn't mean that this user should have his own VP. If company has VP, the user in this company can submit his transaction using other VPs and result will be the same.